# How to remove extra spaces between two ticks in d3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I want to remove extra space between two dates,
here is img of x-axis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wknp9.png

```
dates array=["2016-03-04", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-08", "2016-03-09", "2016-03-10", "2016-03-11", "2016-03-14", "2016-03-15", "2016-03-16", "2016-03-17", "2016-03-18"];
var x = d3.time.scale()       
    .range([margin.left + padding, width + padding - 350])   
    .domain(d3.extent(dates, function (d) { return timeFormat.parse(d) }));
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()        
    .scale(x)       
    .orient("top")        
    .tickFormat(timeFormat)        
    .tickValues(dates.map(function (d) { return timeFormat.parse(d) }));
```

Comment: you have more than two dates there

Comment: there is array of dates

Comment: basically you want the difference between the divs to be consistent ?

Comment: yup I want to remove that extra space between two dates

Comment: It depends more specifically on what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide an image of how you want the chart to look — not just the axis? If you're drawing a trendline, then the question is are you trying to "compress" time between those ticks in order to keep them equidistant? If not, then what do you expect to happen to any interim values between ticks? If you're just drawing a barchart, and you simply want a bar per tick, then you shouldn't use a time scale, you should use an ordinal scale. And it's also possible that you should use an ordinal scale even if you're drawing a trendline.